# service not deployed onto NGINX kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

So this is my current setup.

I have a k8 cluster with nginx controller installed. I installed nginx using helm.

So I have a simple apple service as below:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-app
  labels:
    app: apple
spec:
  containers:
    - name: apple-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=apple"

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apple
  ports:
    - port: 5678 # Default port for image
```

and then I did a kubectl apply -f apples.yaml

Now i have an ingress.yaml as below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          backend:
            serviceName: apple-service
            servicePort: 5678
```

and then I kubectl -f ingress.yaml

my ingress controller doesnt have an external ip address.

But even without the external ip, I did a

```
kubectl exec -it nginxdeploy-nginx-ingress-controller-5d6ddbb677-774xc /bin/bash
```

And tried doing a curl kL http://localhost/apples

and its giving me a 503 error.

Anybody can help on this?

Comment: You'd want `http://localhost/apple` right, not `/apples`? Also, don't forget that nginx ingress just generates a normal `nginx.conf` file in those Pods, so you can look for yourself to see what it thinks is going on

Comment: Hey matthew, yes you are right. its apple instead of apples. I did actually look at my logs and the path is there www-data@nginxdeploy-nginx-ingress-controller-5d6ddbb677-774xc:/etc/nginx$ cat nginx.conf | grep apple
                location /apple {
                        set $service_name   "apple-service";
                        set $location_path  "/apples";

Comment: Weird, I can't imagine where it would be getting `"/apples";` from, based on the snippets you have posted. Anyway, did curl-ing to `/apple` still produce the 503?

Comment: It now gives me a  http://localhost/apple
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.15.3</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I am not 100% sure why this is happening. Just to make sure, can you verify that the apple-service is actually running and doing what is supposed to do by using the command `curl http://apple-service.default:5678/` in the ingress controller pod after you do `kubectl exec -it nginxdeploy-nginx-ingress-controller-5d6ddbb677-774xc /bin/bash`. If the apple-service is not responding, then it is the reason why you are getting 503, which might be caused by the fact that the pod is killed.

Comment: @Adam If you are getting 308, you should try the https endpoint.

Comment: Moreover, it is generally not recommended to create Pods, since they are not supervised by Kubernetes like Deployments, i.e. they are not recreated when they die, which might cause the service to be unavailable when they die.

Comment: @XiaoLiang not sure if its an https endpoint issue as I didnt deploy any certificates on ngingx and was following this guide here. https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html     only difference is im using helm to install nginx

Comment: First of all, you are missing `targetPort` in the `Service`. Seems like you have followed official documentation examples. Unfortunately, this will not work as you expect

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your configuration, and it seems to be working fine to me.

Pod responds fine:

```
$ kubectl describe pod apple-app

Name:         apple-app
Namespace:    default
Node:         kube-helm/10.156.0.2
Start Time:   Mon, 10 Sep 2018 11:53:57 +0000
Labels:       app=apple
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.73.73
...

$ curl http://192.168.73.73:5678
apple
```

Service responds fine:

```
$ kubectl get service 

NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
apple-service   ClusterIP   10.111.93.194    <none>        5678/TCP   1m

$ curl http://10.111.93.194:5678
apple
```

Ingress also responds fine, but by default it redirects http to https:

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-6c9fcdf8d9-ggrcs -n ingress-nginx /bin/bash

www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-6c9fcdf8d9-ggrcs:/etc/nginx$ curl http://localhost/apple

<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.12</center>
</body>
</html>

www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-6c9fcdf8d9-ggrcs:/etc/nginx$ curl -k https://localhost/apple
apple
```

If you check the nginx configuration in controller pod, you will see that redirect configuration for /apple location:

```
www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-6c9fcdf8d9-ggrcs:/etc/nginx$ more  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
...

                location /apple {

                        set $namespace      "default";
                        set $ingress_name   "example-ingress";
                        set $service_name   "apple-service";
                        set $service_port   "5678";
                        set $location_path  "/apple";

                        rewrite_by_lua_block {

                        }

                        log_by_lua_block {

                                monitor.call()
                        }

                        if ($scheme = https) {
                                more_set_headers                        "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=1572
4800; includeSubDomains";
                        }

                        port_in_redirect off;

                        set $proxy_upstream_name "default-apple-service-5678";

                        # enforce ssl on server side
                        if ($redirect_to_https) {

                                return 308 https://$best_http_host$request_uri;

                        }

                        client_max_body_size                    "1m";

                        proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;

                        # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

                        # Allow websocket connections
                        proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

                        proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

                        proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $the_real_ip;

                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $the_real_ip;

                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

                        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI         $request_uri;

                        proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

                        # Pass the original X-Forwarded-For
                        proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

                        # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
                        # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
                        proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

                        # Custom headers to proxied server

                        proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
                        proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
                        proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

                        proxy_buffering                         "off";
                        proxy_buffer_size                       "4k";
                        proxy_buffers                           4 "4k";
                        proxy_request_buffering                 "on";

                        proxy_http_version                      1.1;

                        proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
                        proxy_cookie_path                       off;

                        # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
                        proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
                        proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;

                        proxy_pass http://default-apple-service-5678;

                        proxy_redirect                          off;

                }
```

You can disable this default behavior by adding [annotations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1567#issuecomment-364649925):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          backend:
            serviceName: apple-service
            servicePort: 5678


www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-6c9fcdf8d9-ggrcs:/etc/nginx$ curl http://localhost/apple
apple
```

Comment: Hi Vas, thanks for this. Did you use helm to install the controller?

Comment: No, at the beginning it was installed manually. Then I reinstalled it using helm and found no any difference in it's behavior. Ingress object without annotation let the ingress-controller redirects me from HTTP to HTTPS, but with mentioned annotations ingress-controller allows me to use both HTTP and HTTPS for location /apple.